# Why doesn't pressing the up arrow get the previous command in nested processes

Tags: windows, terminal, process

On the command line, I can retrieve previous commands by pressing the up / down arrow keys. This doesn't work however if I nest CMDs beyond a certain depth. Why is that so and is there a way to make it work?

To reproduce, open CMD and run:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>cmd
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1110]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\>echo lands
lands

C:\>rem Pressing up here doesn't bring back "echo lands"
```

---

For more context:

I have a REPL in my Python [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/) bot which uses a subclass of the builtin *code* module's [InteractiveConsole](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#code.InteractiveConsole) class that supports getting previous lines using the arrow keys (tested it by itself). I use [Pew](https://pypi.org/project/pew/) to run my bot in the right virtual environment (with `pew in bot python bot.py`).

The arrow keys don't work. When I run my bot, Task Manager shows 6 extra processes (processes other than the original cmd.exe and Console Window Host):

```
pew     # Pew's executable on the PATH
python  # Pew's virtual environment's Python
python  # Global Python
cmd     # Pew does subprocess.run(..., shell=True)
python  # Bot's virtual environment's Python
python  # Global Python
```

To confirm that it was solely the number of nested processes that mattered, I tried two more things. First, I installed Pew globally (with `pip install pew`) and ran the bot using `python -m pew ...`. There were 4 extra processes (3 Pythons and 1 CMD) and the arrow keys still didn't work. Then, I made a fork of Pew that doesn't create an intermediate shell and ran the bot using it. There were 3 extra processes (all Pythons) and the arrow keys worked inside the REPL.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this happens, but I've resorted to using [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/) which doesn't suffer from this issue.